# How can I provide the PropTypes for a inner, nested component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component that is rather complex, so I build it from nested components. Simplified:

```
export function BlockProvideFeedback(props) {  
  const handleSelect = (event) => console.log(event);

  const Form = (props) => (
    <>
      <RadioList selected={props.selected} />
      <Button onClick={handleSelect} />
    </>
  );

  const Message = () => (
    <p>Thanks for the feedback</p>
  );

  if (props.feedbackStatus == 'agreed') {
    return(<Form selected='done'/>);
  if (props.feedbackStatus == 'pending') {
    return(<Form selected='needswork'/>);
  } else {
    return(<Message/>);
  }
};

BlockProvideFeedback.propTypes = {
  feedbackStatus: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

The linter is, rightfully IMO, pointing out that `props.selected` in `Form(props)` needs propTypes. But I don't know where and how to provide them. *'selected' is missing in props validation*.

I tried the obvious:

```
BlockProvideFeedback().Form.propTypes { //... }
```

But that throws errors because I'm instantiating the component (by calling the function) without the proper context, props, providers etc.

How do I put `selected` for my nested component, in a props validation?

Or am I maybe doing something else horribly wrong: for example, my entire setup of nesting the  maybe is so non-react-ish that tooling, like linters, will fail on it without being able to solve it?

Comment: May I ask you why you are declaring the `Form` and `Message` component inside the `BlockProvideFeedback` one, instead of having them as separate components?

Comment: @secan: two reasons, really. First is that in my more complex implementation, the `<Form>` uses the parent `<BlockProvideFeedback>` state and helpers. In the example I indicated this with the `handleSelect`. If they were separate components I'd either need to extract that state and such methods, or pass them along. And secondly: they are not really components: never re-used, never exported etc. Conceptually they aren't standalone things, really.

Comment: I would try adding `Form.propTypes = { //... }` right after you define `Form`.

Comment: But, if `Form` "lives and dies" inside `BlockProvideFeedback` and it is not reused anywhere else, there should be no need for typechecking its props: it cannot happen that another component uses it and try to poass a number to the `selected` prop.

Comment: @secan good argument. By that reasoning, the linter is simply wrong and should be ignored there. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Form` and `Message` are not intended to be shared and reused, I would convert them in "render functions"; something like:

```
export function BlockProvideFeedback(props) {  
  const handleSelect = (event) => console.log(event);

  const renderForm = (selectedVal) => (
    <>
      <RadioList selected={selectedVal} />
      <Button onClick={handleSelect} />
    </>
  );

  const renderMessage = () => (
    <p>Thanks for the feedback</p>
  );

  if (props.feedbackStatus == 'agreed') {
    return renderForm('done');
  if (props.feedbackStatus == 'pending') {
    return renderForm('needswork');
  } else {
    return renderMessage();
  }
};

BlockProvideFeedback.propTypes = {
  feedbackStatus: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Not really an answer to your question, I know, but it seems to me this case can be a sort of "XY problem".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was aware of the XY-ness of my question, hence the last question paragraph.